# Server settings for posting checkbox & nesting values in PHP

Tags: php, server

I have form regarding add product. This is a big form containing lots of input fields, nested loops, add more functionality. When I fill all the fields & submit the form on my local machine & also on my demo server, it submitted successfully. But the same code is not working on client's live server. Database, database records, source code files all are same but it does not work on live server.

It shows the message like "Product added successfully" on live server but in actual id doesn't.

For e.g. there are 92 colors with checkbox option available on add product page & When I check one of the color it shows the section where I can add more information about that colored product like size, price, quantity(add more functionality for this section).

Likewise I checked all the colors & fill the information about all colors respectively. after submitting I print the posted value & found that it post sum of the records out of 92 colors which I select & fill the information of them.

Same criteria, same database, same source code files works on my local machine, demo server but it does not work on live server.

Someone suggest me that check the server config for max_input_nesting_level, max_input vars etc. I also thinks that there is some sever setting I need to do for the same but what are they I don't know.

Comment: You should provide a little more information, e.g. pastebins to your config files on your local dev server and the clients' config (make sure to cut our sensitive information).

Comment: You can check my demo server configuration settings here :

http://www.techmodi.com/demo/nz/phpinfo.php

Live Server configuration settings : 

http://www.nz-lifestyle.com/phpinfo.php

Comment: Can anyone suggest the solution?

Answer (score 0):

There is a setting in php_ini namely "post_max_size" increase its limit to 250M or some greater No, notice the `M` after 250M it stands for MB in post data

Comment: I have already increased the size..you can check all the server configuration settings here http://www.nz-lifestyle.com/phpinfo.php

Comment: Hello Arpita..Can you please suggest the solution?

Comment: Can You just check print all the post variables in the first line of the script `if(!empty($_POST)){print_r($_POST)}` and check if you are getting all the variables over there

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer for above criteria. I have increased the size of "max_input_vars" from php.ini file & it works!!